# pyodbc Installation Issue on Plone Python Path

Tags: python, plone, zope, pyodbc

How do you install pyodbc package on a Linux (RedHat server RHEL) onto a Zope/Plone bundled Python path instead of in the global Python path?

yum install pyodbc and python setup.py install, all put pyodbc in the sys python path.

I read articles about putting pyodbc in python2.4/site-packages/
I tried that, but it didn't work for my Plone external method, which still complains about no module named pyodbc.

Answer (score 1):

Add the package to the eggs section in buildout and then re-run buildout.

There might be additional server requirements to install pyodbc.